# Resize only one edge

Tags: css, css-transforms

How could you resize only one edge of a block-element? I thought about using a rotation (transform-origin on the other edge then rotate around the center), but it'll look different, when it is placed on another point on the viewport (because of the perspective). I saw the transform: matrix() property, but it seems that this will only allow to scale the local vectors of the element.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if edge = border in your case. Try this, if is:

```css
div {
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
}

.border {
    border:#CCCCCC 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.transition {
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.border:hover {
    border-bottom-left-radius:20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border transition"></div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cfuwb/)

Comment: Well, thanks, but I meant edge. I want to resize one edge of an element and ist content should be scaled as well (like using a rotation)

Comment: I've been playing around to make it work how you want, but with no luck. Maybe someone will post an answer, if it's possible to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your work. Your solution might come in handy sometimes else :)